# Chunks creation based on modules in Webpack 4 with SplitChunksPlugin

Tags: webpack, chunks, code-splitting, webpack-4

The creation of common chunks wasn't my forte in Webpack 3 but now is more confusing than ever.

What I'm trying to achieve:

First of all, the webpack configuration below regards to management of javascript dependencies for a Wordpress Theme.

I have only one entry point, which includes several modules some of them used in specific pages.

So firstly I need to create seperate chunks for modules such as slick slider(useful only in product page), secondly other common modules from node_modules(like jquery) to be included in vendor.js bundle and finally the rest to be included in the app.js bundle.

Current configuration generates 3 bundles: app, slick, simplebar.

Any ideas what's wrong with configuration?

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

module.exports = {
// Where to start bundling
entry: {
    app: "./js/assets/src/app.js",
},

// Where to output
output: {
    // Output to the same directory
    path:  __dirname + '/js/assets/dist',

    // Capture name from the entry using a pattern
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: "vendor",
                chunks: "initial",
                priority: -10,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
            simplebar: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]simplebar[\\/]/,
                name: "simplebar",
                chunks: "all",
            },
            slick : {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]slick-carousel[\\/]/,
                name: "slick",
                chunks: "all",
            },
        },
    },
},
// How to resolve encountered imports
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: "babel-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'jQuery'
            },{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '$'
            }]
        }
    ],
},
devtool: 'source-map',
// What extra processing to perform
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['js/assets/dist']),
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
        sourceMap: true
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'static'
    })
],

// Adjust module resolution algorithm
resolve: {},
};
```